# How to use a verb 'CHANGE' in this situation?

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's the context.

I loved fried chicken but my ex said it is too grisy and unhealthy. And unbelieveably, I became sick of eating it. In this situation, can I say like this?

> 1. She changed me in the way I eat.
> 2. I have changed in the way I eat because of my ex.
> 3. She affected me in the way I eat.
> 4. She has changed the way I eat by saying that fried chicken is unhealthy.
> 5. The way I eat has changed because of my ex.

I think all of these are possible to use, but I am only comfortable with #5,4. Are all of them possible to use with out changing meaning?

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker but I would say: "She's changed how I eat fried chicken".

Comment: @KhanhTranDinh: Since jihoon says he doesn't each fried chicken anymore, perhaps "*how I eat fried chicken*" is not what is intended.

Comment: @jihoon, I am wondering if it is really the way you eat [that was changed/affected]. I think it's your PREFERENCE? Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all of them are possible to use without changing meaning. The only one I'm doubting about is the third one, because 'affecting' is something else than 'changing'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would say it:

Example #1:

> I have changed my eating habits because my ex once told me that fried chicken was bad for my health.

Example #2:

> My ex completely changed my eating habits by telling me that eating fried chicken is actually quite unhealthy.